# Java - trouble with Comparable

Tags: java, comparable

I am writing a Java program to sort numbers in different ways. I am stuck with a certain part of this. The structure of my program means that each sort MUST have a method of sort(Comparable[] items, int cutoff), but the method for my bucket sort only takes in an int array parameter. This is the code for my class (adapted from geekviewpoint.com):

```
public class BucketSort {

public void sort(Comparable[] items, int cutoff) {
    bucketSort(items);
}

public void bucketSort(int[] input) {
      //get hash codes
      final int[] code = hash(input);
      //create and initialize buckets to ArrayList: O(n)
      List<Integer>[] buckets = new List[code[1]];
      for (int i = 0; i < code[1]; i++) {
        buckets[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      }
      //distribute data into buckets: O(n)
      for (int i : input) {
        buckets[hash(i, code)].add(i);
      }

      for (List bucket : buckets) {
        Collections.sort(bucket);
      }
      int ndx = 0;
      //merge the buckets: O(n)
      for (int b = 0; b < buckets.length; b++) {
        for (int v : buckets[b]) {
          input[ndx++] = v;
        }
      }
    }

    private int[] hash(int[] input) {
      int m = input[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (m < input[i]) {
          m = input[i];
        }
      }
      return new int[]{m, (int) Math.sqrt(input.length)};
    }

    private int hash(int i, int[] code) {
      return (int) ((double) i / code[0] * (code[1] - 1));
    }
}
```

The problem comes when calling the bucketSort(items) method in the top sort method, with the error reading as:

The method bucketSort(int[]) in the type BucketSort is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable[])

I ideally need to only change code in this class, rather than the class where I am calling the sort method from. The format of the top sort method also must stay the same, in terms of its parameters. I hope I am explaining myself clearly. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does your public `sort` method *need* a `Comparable[]` parameter?  `Comparable[]` implies that the parameter can be an array of *any* object type that implements `Comparable`, including `String` and lots of others.  But the implementation seems to think it should be getting only integers.  What's it supposed to do if you give it a `String[]`?  I think we need more info about why you're "stuck" with a `Comparable[]` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Use an array of Integer instead of int. Integer implements Comparable and in this way, the cast works.

Comment: No, you would be right if he were trying to cast an `int[]` to a `Comparable[]`.  But he's going in the other direction.

Comment: `Comparable -> Integer` is a narrowing conversion.

Comment: It will compile if `int[]` is replaced by `Integer[]` throughout the class **and** if the call to `bucketSort` is changed to `bucketSort((Integer[])items);` (and some unrelated errors are fixed).  But that's a pretty suspicious-looking cast.

Comment: It seems that he is only expecting Integers, since there are no other branches to be taken in the code, just the direct cast to int. It's not a pretty solution (since the requirements don't allow to something better), but as ajb said, is not impossible. You could just add a validation before the cast.